# Error: Insufficient Scope Permissions

Tags: html, asp.net, http-post, stocktwits

I am developing a web application to post to stocktwits wall. Now I am getting an error: Insufficient Scope Permissions. Can anybody tell me where the error is?

My Code is:

```
<form name="chart" method="post" action="https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json?access_token=657c40d5a04615c973d474745f8f1311960dcc6d">
    <a id="post">Message Posting</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Comment: This means when you authorize the user account to your app you might not have passed the correct permissions or scope. You will want to make sure you pass: publish_messages

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading more on http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api especially http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication#scopes.

The message is self evident - you do not have enough permission for this API call.